# Differential Equation for equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the solution of the differential equation 
$$\left(y\left(1 + \frac{1}{x} \right) + \sin y\right)\,dx+ (x + \ln x + x \cos y)\,dy = 0$$

I am trying to convert this equation into $\frac{dy}{dx} +P(x) y =Q(x)$ to simplify it but unable to get desired

Comment: What are your initial attempts? At first glance, it seems unlikely that you can work it into the form you desire because of the $\sin(y)$

Comment: Note MathJax usage issues, as in my edit to the question. $$ (y(1 + \frac{1}{x}) + siny)dx+ (x + lnx + x cosy)dy = 0 \\  \text{versus} \\ \left(y\left(1 + \frac{1}{x} \right) + \sin y\right)\,dx+ (x + \ln x + x \cos y)\,dy = 0 $$

Comment: ($\color{red}{y} + \color{blue}{\frac{y}{x}}  + \sin y) \,dx+ ( \color{red}{x} + \color{blue}{\ln x} + x \cos y)\,dy = 0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the way this equation is set up, you may not be able to achieve the desired form. However, the given equation is of the type 
$$M \, dx + N \, dy=0,$$
where, 
\begin{align*}
M & = y\left(1 + \frac{1}{x} \right) + \sin y\\
N & = x + \ln x + x \cos y.
\end{align*}
It is easy to see that 
$$\frac{\partial{M}}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial{N}}{\partial x}=1+\frac{1}{x}+\cos y.$$
So this is what is referred to as an **exact equation** (see link posted by Sean Roberson in the comments). The idea is that there is a function $F(x,y)$ such that 
$$\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial x}=M \qquad \text{ and } \qquad \frac{\partial{F}}{\partial y}=N.$$
Now try solving these to get $F$.

Comment: If the OP needs a reference, here's a thing I wrote a few years ago: http://www.math.tamu.edu/~szroberson/ExactODE_SZR.pdf

Comment: @SeanRoberson Thanks for the link. Surely it will benefit OP.

Comment: +1, you had *exact*ly the same idea as I did! (No pun intended)